# How to enable automatic update in wordpress running on IIS7 and Windows 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, wordpress

I have a dedicated server using Windows 2008 and IIS7 running 5 blogs with Wordpress. I can't use the autoupdate feature of the wordpress neither the automatic plugin instalation.

I believe I must set writing permissions in some temporary folder, the question is which one. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Wordpress on Windows 2008 IIS requires that you grant read permissons to the IUSR account and the IIS_IUSR account on the root folder.  If you want to add attachments with your posts then you need to add write access to IUSR on the wp-content/upload folder.

If you want to be able to dynamic updates to plugins and such then you need to grant write access to the wp-content folder.  I would recommend only granting write permissions to the wp-content folder when you are performing upgrades, and then remove the permission when you have finished.

I wrote [an article about this](http://www.dscoduc.com/2009/11/acl-settings-for-wordpress-on-iis/) on my blog after working through the same questions.

Comment: I am posting this as an answer ONLY because I do not have the reputation on Server Fault to leave a comment or upvote. The answer posted by "Dscoduc" worked perfect for me on IIS 7 with Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change the NTFS permissions so that the local system account has write access to the folder for these updaters to work.  That or configure the application pool to run under a local or domain account which has write access to the folder.