# What user should an application pool bound to a Wordpress site use in IIS?

Tags: security, iis-7, web-server, permissions, wordpress

I've installed a wordpress site in a dedicated server with Windows 2008 server running IIS7 but I'm a little confused on what's the most secure way to set the appropriate file settings.

The thing is the automatic update and automatic plugin installation only works if I give Full Control permission to the Everyone user in the root folder where wordpress is installed.

I'm not sure how dangerous this setting is, but I can imagine it's not the best scenario. That being said, what's the user I should use in the application pool used by this site, so that I can set a more restrictive security permission in the folders used by wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this similar question](https://serverfault.com/questions/51637/how-to-enable-automatic-update-in-wordpress-running-on-iis7-and-windows-2008/213550#213550) on serverfault. The answer by "Dscoduc" was spot on and worked for me.